# Implementing sort by date added in mongo

Tags: arrays, mongodb, sorting, timestamp

I have a customer model containing an array of favorites that reference product id's in another collection:

```
{
    name: string,
    favorites: [ObjectId("123"), ObjectId("456"), ObjectId("789")]
}
```

Now I'm looking to let a customer sort their favorites list by the date they added the favorite...what would be the best way to store favorites with this new requirement? does Mongo allow built-in timestamps at the array element level?

Comment: If you push the favorites to the array as they are added, won't the array naturally be in order of date added?

Comment: yep i forgot to mention that we were originally using addToSet to prevent duplicates but ran into the ordering problem. Looks like the $push method preserves order..but do you know how we can prevent duplicates with that?